# Spark: produce RDD[(X, X)] of all possible combinations from RDD[X]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is it possible in Spark to implement '.combinations' function from scala collections?

```
   /** Iterates over combinations.
   *
   *  @return   An Iterator which traverses the possible n-element combinations of this $coll.
   *  @example  `"abbbc".combinations(2) = Iterator(ab, ac, bb, bc)`
   */
```

For example how can I get from RDD[X] to RDD[List[X]] or RDD[(X,X)] for combinations of size = 2. And lets assume that all values in RDD are unique.

Comment: Not that the answer you accepted is not 2 element combinations but the cartesian product, also your example is contradictory because you say the RDD is unique but it has 3 `b`s

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Cartesian product and combinations are two different things, the cartesian product will create an RDD of size `rdd.size() ^ 2` and combinations will create an RDD of size `rdd.size() choose 2`

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 5)
val combinations = rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter{ case (a,b) => a < b }`.
combinations.collect()
```

Note this will only work if an ordering is defined on the elements of the list, since we use `<`. This one only works for choosing two but can easily be extended by making sure the relationship `a < b` for all a and b in the sequence

Answer (score 3):

This is supported natively by a Spark RDD with the `cartesian` transformation.

e.g.:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 5)
val cartesian = rdd.cartesian(rdd)
cartesian.collect

Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), 
(2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), 
(3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4), (3,5), 
(4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4), (4,5), 
(5,1), (5,2), (5,3), (5,4), (5,5))
```

Comment: This is not combinations, this is product, the set of 2 combinations is `n C 2` the size of cartesian is size `n^2`

Comment: That being said not fully sure how to efficiently do combinations in spark

Comment: @aaronman you're right. I guess I jumped directly from the title of the question to the answer. I answered a similar Q today that required combinations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557078/how-to-transform-scala-nested-map-operation-to-scala-spark-operation  Not sure how to port that recursive code to Spark.

Comment: if you look at [`CartesianRDD`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/CartesianRDD.scala) you can probably use similar logic, seem like a little too much work for an answer though

Comment: @aaronman I crafted a working algo inspired by the recursive scala version. I'll post on a new answer.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed, `cartesian` will give you n^2 elements of the cartesian product of the RDD with itself. 
This algorithm computes the combinations (n,2) of an RDD without having to compute the n^2 elements first:  (used String as type, generalizing to a type T takes some plumbing with classtags that would obscure the purpose here)

This is probably less time efficient that cartesian + filtering due to the iterative `count` and `take` actions that forces the computation of the RDD, but more space efficient as it calculates only the `C(n,2) = n!/(2*(n-2))! = (n*(n-1)/2)` elements instead of the `n^2` of the cartesian product.

```
 import org.apache.spark.rdd._

 def combs(rdd:RDD[String]):RDD[(String,String)] = {
    val count = rdd.count
    if (rdd.count < 2) { 
        sc.makeRDD[(String,String)](Seq.empty)
    } else if (rdd.count == 2) {
        val values = rdd.collect
        sc.makeRDD[(String,String)](Seq((values(0), values(1))))
    } else {
        val elem = rdd.take(1)
        val elemRdd = sc.makeRDD(elem)
        val subtracted = rdd.subtract(elemRdd)  
        val comb = subtracted.map(e  => (elem(0),e))
        comb.union(combs(subtracted))
    } 
 }
```

Comment: When you say "probably less time efficient that cartesian + filtering" -- do you mean doing `rdd.cartesian(rdd).distinct().collect()`?

Answer (score 2):

This creates all combinations (n, 2) and works for any RDD without requiring any ordering on the elements of RDD.

```
val rddWithIndex = rdd.zipWithIndex
rddWithIndex.cartesian(rddWithIndex).filter{case(a, b) => a._2 < b._2}.map{case(a, b) => (a._1, b._1)}
```

a._2 and b._2 are the indices, while a._1 and b._1 are the elements of the original RDD.

Example:

Note that, no ordering is defined on the maps here.

```
val m1 = Map('a' -> 1, 'b' -> 2)
val m2 = Map('c' -> 3, 'a' -> 4)
val m3 = Map('e' -> 5, 'c' -> 6, 'b' -> 7)
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(Array(m1, m2, m3))
val rddWithIndex = rdd.zipWithIndex
rddWithIndex.cartesian(rddWithIndex).filter{case(a, b) => a._2 < b._2}.map{case(a, b) => (a._1, b._1)}.collect
```

Output:

```
Array((Map(a -> 1, b -> 2),Map(c -> 3, a -> 4)), (Map(a -> 1, b -> 2),Map(e -> 5, c -> 6, b -> 7)), (Map(c -> 3, a -> 4),Map(e -> 5, c -> 6, b -> 7)))
```