# self join in spark with scala api

Tags: list, scala, apache-spark, rdd, haversine

Earlier I posted a problem of self join in scala. I am trying to implement the same in Spark but not able to convert. Here is the problem and my code. 
Input data set...

`Proprty_ID,  latitude,    longitude, Address
123,    33.84,  -118.39, null
234,    35.89,  -119.48, null
345,    35.34,  -119.39, null`

Output data set

`Property_ID1, Property_ID2, distance
123,123,0
123,234,0.1
123,345,0.6
234,234,0
234,123,0.1
234,345,0.7
345,345,0
345,123,0.6
345,234,0.7`

Spark Code:

```
`import math._

object Haversine {
   val R = 6372.8  //radius in km

   def haversine(lat1:Double, lon1:Double, lat2:Double, lon2:Double)={
      val dLat=(lat2 - lat1).toRadians
      val dLon=(lon2 - lon1).toRadians

      val a = pow(sin(dLat/2),2) + pow(sin(dLon/2),2) * cos(lat1.toRadians) * cos(lat2.toRadians)
      val c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
      R * c
   }

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      println(haversine(36.12, -86.67, 33.94, -118.40))
  }
}

class SimpleCSVHeader(header:Array[String]) extends Serializable {
  val index = header.zipWithIndex.toMap
  def apply(array:Array[String], key:String):String = array(index(key))
}


val csv = sc.textFile("geo.csv")  // original file
val data = csv.map(line => line.split(",").map(elem => elem.trim)) //lines in rows
val header = new SimpleCSVHeader(data.take(1)(0)) // we build our header with the first line
val rows = data.filter(line => header(line,"latitude") != "latitude") // filter the header out

// val users = rows.map(row => header(row,"user")
// val usersByHits = rows.map(row => header(row,"user") -> header(row,"hits").toInt)

val typed = rows.map{ case Array(id, lat, lon) => (id, lat.toDouble, lon.toDouble)}
```

`

After this I need to do the self join on typed and pass it thru the Haversine method. 
I got the Scala code as below from community which I need to convert it to Spark code to work with RDDs. Below code is currently working for lists.

```
`val combos = for {
    a <- typed
    b <- typed
  } yield (a,b)

combos.map{ case ((id1, lat1, lon1), (id2, lat2, lon2)) 
     => id1 + "," + id2 + "," + haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)} foreach println`
```

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spark operation you want is `cartesian`.  You can learn more at [Spark: produce RDD[(X, X)] of all possible combinations from RDD[X]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557873/spark-produce-rddx-x-of-all-possible-combinations-from-rddx).