# Spark task optimisation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, optimization, bigdata

I am trying to find an optimised way to generate a list of unique co-location pairings. I have looked to do this using a series of flatmaps and distinct queries but I have found the flatmap to be not overly performant when running over millions of records. Any help in optimising this would be gratefully received.

The dataset is (geohash, id) and I am running this on 30 Node Cluster.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("gh5", "id1"), ("gh4", "id1"), ("gh5", "id2"),("gh5", "id3"))

val uniquePairings = rdd.groupByKey().map(value =>
     value._2.toList.sorted.combinations(2).map{
     case Seq(x, y) => (x, y)}.filter(id => 
     id._1 != id._2)).flatMap(x => x).distinct()       

voutput = Array(("id1","id2"),("id1","id3"),("id2","id3"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `join` should be more than enough here. For example with `DataFrames`:

```
val df = rdd.toDF
df.as("df1").join(df.as("df2"),
  ($"df1._1" === $"df2._1") && 
  ($"df1._2" < $"df2._2")
).select($"df1._2", $"df2._2")
```

or datasets

```
val ds = rdd.toDS
ds.as("ds1").joinWith(ds.as("ds2"),
  ($"ds1._1" === $"ds2._1") && 
  ($"ds1._2" < $"ds2._2")
).map{ case ((_, x), (_, y)) => (x, y)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response do the data frames provide any performance benefits of the join in terms of shuffling.

Comment: Not one I am aware of but it is more efficient than standard co-group `join` on RDDs.

Comment: Thanks I ran a slightly altered version to sort the keys first so that the lookups should be more likely to take place locally. I presume Spark will look locally first?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the cartesian function. It produces an RDD that is all possible combinations of the input RDDs. Do note that this is an expensive operation (N^2 in the size of the RDD)

[Cartesian example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557873/spark-produce-rddx-x-of-all-possible-combinations-from-rddx)

Comment: Thanks for the response but running the same function using a Cartesian appears much slower. I assume this is because it's not a true n^2 problem.

Comment: Certainly could be. It might be worth trying to cache your RDD before the Cartesian operation. Thinking about this some more, your original approach feels like the best way to accomplish this task. But, you should use reduceByKey instead of groupByKey. This task is associative (so you don't need groupByKey) and reduceByKey will save on some data shuffling (https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)

Comment: Thanks again I have written a combineByKey in my full example as the data structure is slightly more complex than the example but thanks for the heads up. The task seems to be taking about 4-5 hours for 11 million records which just seems a tad on the high side. Not sure if this is in fact realistic.