# Alternative method to generate a cartesian product in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

Currently in my spark code I'm doing the following :

```
rdd2 = rdd1.cartesian(rdd1)
rdd2.filter( remove_some_data filter)
```

Turns out it computes the complete cartesian first and then filters out the unnecessary combinations.

Instead is there a way to create a PairRDD with only the combinations that I want?

In more detail :

I have an RDD on N items.

Cartesian product yields N x N items. 
I want only unique interactions between these N items.

i.e For user 1 : N-1 pairs
For user 2 : N-2 Pairs
For user 3 : N-3 Pairs
.
.
.
For user N-1 : 1 Pair

So a total of 1 + 2 + .... + (N-1) elements in the PairRDD.

How I'm achieving this currently is by using

```
rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter(my_filter_function).
```

Instead I directly want to arrive at the end result combinations.

Comment: Can you please share data structure of user table

Comment: So you would like to do a `cartesian` and a `filter` without doing a `cartesian` and a `filter`??

Comment: have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557873/spark-produce-rddx-x-of-all-possible-combinations-from-rddx). The most efficient seems to be rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter{ case (a,b) => a < b }, there is no magical function to do this 2 step in 1

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt That's correct

Answer (score 0):

Slide 20 from this slidedeck proposes an alternative, although I haven't tried it myself yet. Link: https://www.slideshare.net/databricks/optimizing-apache-spark-sql-joins

The relevant excerpt is:

> 1. Create an RDD of UID by UID
> 2. Force a Broadcast of the rows of the table
> 3. Call a UDF given the UID by UID to look up the table rows and perform your calculation
> 4. Time your calculation on a sample set to size your cluster