# Spark RDD get all possible pair combinations with a list of ids

Tags: python, pyspark

I have an rdd of business ids

```
rdd => ['business_id1', 'business_id2', 'business_id3']
```

How can I create all combination of business Id pairs using Itertools in spark in a distributed way in python

Comment: You will have to write your own version of `itertools.combinations` function which works for a distributed list. You can try using `rdd.cartesian(rdd)` which gives you all the combinations and then try to filter out from the resulting `rdd` as per your requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark: produce RDD\[(X, X)\] of all possible combinations from RDD\[X\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557873/spark-produce-rddx-x-of-all-possible-combinations-from-rddx)