# Spark: Get combinations of predefined length

Tags: python, pyspark

Given a an rdd with multiple tuples, how do I obtain all combinations of a given length? Say I have

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
elements = sc.parallelize([('A','B'), ('D','E'), ('G','H')])
```

and some length parameter, say `length=3`

I'd like to obtain

```
res = [('A','B','D'), ('A','B','E'), ('A','B','G'), ('A','B','H'), ('D','E','G'), ('D','E','H')]
```

I found this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557873/spark-produce-rddx-x-of-all-possible-combinations-from-rddx), but unfortunately none of the answers address the problem of predefined length.

Comment: Could you extend the output to somewhat complicated case like :  `sc.parallelize(['ABCDE,'EFGHIJ','KML'])` with length 7

Comment: I edited the question to be more appropriate to my question at hand. Doing length 7 isn't really suited as small working example

Comment: The updated sample looks much more self-contained than the previous format which raised far many questions than it answered.

Comment: Few more questions:
1. What happens when length < num_columns
2. How do you deal with any duplicate entry, in the same row or in different row or in different row as well as different column.