# Writing parallel code for apache Spark

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, apache-spark

Is there a standard set of rules I should follow to ensure that Scala code written for Spark will be run in parallel ?

I find myself writing Spark code which include calls to functions like `map` & `filter` which I think will be run in parallel/distributed. But really I don't know how to test if these functions are run parallel/distributed. Is there texts available which explains this , specifically for Spark, or generic text that can be applied to Spark ?

The two separate answers for this questions : [How to transform Scala nested map operation to Scala Spark operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557078/how-to-transform-scala-nested-map-operation-to-scala-spark-operation) . One answer claims the other answer is not run in parallel. But I'm not sure why to favor one implementation instead of the other.

Comment: I think Spark guide covers this topic very well: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

Comment: If you need more details you can read original paper: https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~matei/papers/2012/nsdi_spark.pdf

Comment: Well, I checked the answers again and I see the source of your confusion. 1) that other answer uses an `rdd.foreach` to run a computation on an rdd. That's wrong as you will not see any results of that computation. 2) I said that it was not running in parallel but on the driver. That's also wrong. `foreach` is an `action` and therefore falls under the category of functions that force an RDD calculation and eventually return an answer to the driver...

Comment: ... but in the particular case of `foreach`, the function if f:T=>Unit and therefore does not return anything. So the computation is actually run on the distributed partitions but you get no results.  Foreach should only be use for side-effect functions, like writing to a DB.

Comment: Sorry for the mess in the comments.

Comment: BTW, did you tried the code? What worked for you?

Comment: @maasg, your comments are interesting enough to write an answer, in my opinion. Transformations / Actions can often be a source of confusion, specially when migrating from Hadoop to Spark.

Comment: @maasg both methods worked, I needed to add } to your code. Question updated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557078/how-to-transform-scala-nested-map-operation-to-scala-spark-operation

Comment: @blue-sky I guess you changed the `for-each`, otherwise I doubt it would work.

Comment: @maasg no i changed the euclDistance function to include a closing }

Answer (score 0):

Keep things in the RDD, ie Map Reduce ReduceBy key groupby etc. Also if you have to do a foreach outside of the rdd use sc.parallelize and then do your for each.